# Disposing CryptoStream vs disposing underlying Stream?

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, stream, garbage-collection

I have a `CryptoStream` with an underlying `Stream`. I can't use a `using` block in order to dispose the `CryptoStream` because that also disposes the underlying `Stream` which I need to leave open. The solution seems to be simply to ignore the `CryptoStream` and just dispose of the `Stream` when needed. But perhaps it is important to keep a reference to the `CryptoStream` and dispose of it to prevent some resources leak?

Additionally, even if I don't dispose the `CryptoStream` might the GC dispose of it if it goes out of scope and then also dispose the underlying `Stream`, (which will be too early because I still need the `Stream`)?

Comment: Are you very sure you need the base stream to remain open? Because it was designed this way for a reason.

Comment: The safest approach is to encrypt to a memorystream and use its buffer after disposing the cryptostream. Recommende for smallish data.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Yes. I need to hash some of the stream and keep processing the rest without a hash CryptoStream .

Comment: Otherwise, make sure you call FlushFinalBuffer and Flush and keep a reference to the CryptoStgream until you're done.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I do Flush the CryptoStream.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Are you saying that the CryptoStream will be disposed by the GC, disposing the Stream?

Answer (score 1):

From [CryptoStream.cs (ln 695)](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/security/cryptography/cryptostream.cs,695):

```
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing) {
        try {
            if (disposing) {
                if (!_finalBlockTransformed) {
                    FlushFinalBlock();
                }
                _stream.Close();
            }                
        }
        finally {
            try {
                // Ensure we don't try to transform the final block again if we get disposed twice
                // since it's null after this
                _finalBlockTransformed = true;
                 // we need to clear all the internal buffers
                 if (_InputBuffer != null)
                     Array.Clear(_InputBuffer, 0, _InputBuffer.Length);
                 if (_OutputBuffer != null)
                     Array.Clear(_OutputBuffer, 0, _OutputBuffer.Length);

                 _InputBuffer = null;
                 _OutputBuffer = null;
                 _canRead = false;
                 _canWrite = false;
            }
            finally {
                 base.Dispose(disposing);
            }
        }
    }
```

As you can see you should call the `FlushFinalBlock` method which is public if you don't want to dispose a `CryptoStream`. This method clears the input and the output buffers so no sensitive information is stored in the used `CryptoStream`.

Might the GC close the underlying `Stream`? Nope. To do that the `Dispose` method must be called with `true` as its argument value, but this is done only in the `Stream.Close` method (called from `Stream.Dispose`). Even if `CryptoStream` would implement a finalizer it isn't a good practice to call `Dispose` on referenced objects when executing `Finalize`. Finalizers should be used only to free unmanaged resources.